# TFS build agent on Azure VM very slow

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, build-agent, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have a TFS build agent installed on Azure VM.

I have a build definition that build micro service project with .net core, its a normal definition that restore, build than publish the project.

The build take around 22 min and the console show that the build is finishing, but it get stuck for around 1 hour then it succeed.

I checked the logs and it doesn't show anything in this time, it only contains the time that the tasks took.

Comment: Is it a hosted agent, or is it an agent you've installed in a VM? Your question title and your question body are contradictory.

Comment: For hosted agents, which means the build running 
on machines managed by Microsoft, then you are actually using Microsoft-hosted CI/CD. 

This uses our [pool of Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=vsts) to run your builds, not on your own Azure VM, could you double confirm this info？

Comment: It's agent installed on my own Azure VM, i will update the question.

Comment: Just check the event log on your client and agent machine, clean caches and refresh browser on client machine, try it again. maybe caused by network issue...

Comment: Nothing work, network and environment are good but still facing the issue.

Comment: @oussamaabdou  Suggest you share some related log which maybe the root cause. Without any useful info, it's too hard to give your some suggestions. If you are worrying about the company info, you could also submit a case in TFS official support site-- [TFS Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html), TFS PM and developers will kindly your issue and log info.

Comment: I checked the logs i found the the agent stuck and repeat the following:
[2018-08-06 15:38:40Z INFO RSAEncryptedFileKeyManager] Loading RSA key parameters from file C:\agent\.credentials_rsaparams
[2018-08-06 16:03:44Z INFO MessageListener] No message retrieved from session 'f6a25e10-4399-49d7-b2f9-c025d5361353' within last 30 minutes.
[2018-08-06 16:33:49Z INFO MessageListener] No message retrieved from session 'f6a25e10-4399-49d7-b2f9-c025d5361353' within last 30 minutes.
[2018-08-06 16:43:51Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Authentication failed with status code 401.